# Fancybox JWplayer onComplete event

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-events, jwplayer

I am trying to close the Fancybox when the video finishes playing. Everything is running as it should when it comes to playing the video. I am not getting anything back on my event `onComplete`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.fancybox({
        fitToView: true,
        content: '<span></span>', // create temp content
        scrolling: 'no', 
        afterLoad: function () {
          this.content = "<embed src='_assets/js/vendor/player.swf?file=../../../_content/test.mp4&autostart=true&amp;wmode=opaque&controlbar.position=over&controlbar.idlehide=true' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='620' height='350'></embed>"; // replace temp content
        },
        events: {
            onComplete: function() {
                alert('Works');
            }
        }
      });
    }); // ready
</script>
```

It would be great if someone can see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: `events` is not a fancybox's option/callback so that will never work. On the other hand, you may need to set an specific listener for your player to detect the end of the video and then call `$.fancybox.close()` method from within that listener. This is how to do it with youtube for instance http://jsfiddle.net/c5h9U/2/

Comment: BTW, `onComplete` is neither a fancybox's v2.x valid callback, use `afterShow` instead.

Comment: Awesome thanks I will have a play and see where I get too.

Answer (score 0):

The onComplete event is meant to go into a jwplayer().setup(), or externally.

As in, add this script somewhere on your page:

```
jwplayer().onComplete(function(event) { alert('Works'); });
```

That should trigger the alert.

Reference - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference